# Name conflicts in Entity Framework using database schemas?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have these two tables in my database:

> client.Employee
>   employee.Employee

When I try to import this into entity framework I get two table objects created:

> Employee
>   Employee1

Is there a way to handle naming conflicts that will work better than this?  And really, I would prefer that my schema is represented some how for non conflicting tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Information about schema is only included in storage description (SSDL) and it is not passed to conceptual model (CSDL) so in conceptual model you have two entities named `Employee` and EF is using the most basic way to resolve that. Another problem is that this probably cannot be modified because generating model from database is not driven by any T4 template which can be changed whereas reverse processing (generating SQL database creation script from model) is.

Comment: Dang.  I thought SQL Server was more fully supported by Entity Framework.  I assumed because they are both Microsoft technologies that they would just work well together.  I should have done more research...  Thanks for your answer.